# When does RenderMode.InteractiveServer establish the session(circuit)?

Tags: blazor-server-side

I am presently using:

```
<component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="Server" />
```

which is working great for me. But DevExpress is requiring `InteractiveServer` for some of their components and so I'll need to convert.

I make a lot of use of the session (circuit) that Blazor establishes for each user. A number of my services are `Scoped`. In addition, I take full advantage of all the permission checks being on the server so a user can't hack around them.

In `InteractiveServer` mode does this all work the same? It creates a session/circuit when a user hits the first page. It's then a SPA and remains in the existing session unless they reload a page in the browser or leave for longer than the session timeout?